# How could I read all objects in my binary file using ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

The `members.bin` file has many object in it, however this list returns only one object when I call this method.

And how could I write objects in binary file so that only one object in each line?

```
public ArrayList<Member> getInfo(){
        FileInputStream fis ;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        Member member ;
        ArrayList<Member> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("members.bin");
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            while((member = (Member)ois.readObject()) != null ){
                list.add(member);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println("IOException 1");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
        }finally{
                try {
                    ois.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("IOException 2");
                }
            }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data from the file?

Comment: Code looks okay at first glance. Are any of your exception messages being printed to the console?

Comment: You could save your whole arraylist as long as the type implements Serializable [click me](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-serialize-arraylist-in-java/) more code is needed for help

Comment: I moved your problem statement before your code. It's usually easier to digest code with a bit of context. Please review [ask] for more tips on asking effective questions.

Comment: erm, you add the same `member` multiple times (but modified) to your list.

Comment: @sschrass I'm not sure that could be the problem...@ashraf try to print something in the while-loop (for eg. `System.out.println("Just read " + member + " and list is of size " + list.size());`, replace member with something you can recognize each object with). It can help you find out if it isn't your file that is causing the problem